# unwanted simultaneous update of all element of list when i want to update just one

Tags: python-3.x, list, printing

Why are all the first elements of each element of visited is changed to True when I have updated only one. I am very new to programming so please excuse if the question is silly. Thanks in advance.

```
visited=[[False]*3]*3
print(visited)    
x=0
y=0
visited[x][y]=True
print(visited)
```

The output is:

```
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]

[[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because you defined the list via:

```
visited=[[False]*3]*3
```

Here, the list is generated by multiplying `[[False]*3]` 3 times. That is, the python stores the 3 elements in the same memory location ( because the 3 are just the same,if I use the correct word, clones). So when you alter one, all gets altered.

Comment: you mean that I created a list of three identical elements, and when one gets updated all are updated?????

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I have clearly understood the point.